# Can a program running in user space and one running in kernel space access the same file in the file system?

Tags: linux, windows, memory, filesystems

I have a C-library that is being used by programs running both in user space and in kernel space. I want the C-library to be able to read from a file stored at some place in the file system. 
Will this be possible or are there any restriction on programs with regards to file access running in either environment?